# How do I move a headline(h2) below the figure and image with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm practicing CSS and I stumbled across a minor problem. I have and article tag with a headline(h2) and a figure. I want to move the headline to be below the figure tag.

[image: How it looks]

I tried to float the headline the right and that worked but the problem was I couldn't get it below the figure. When I obviously made the figure smaller so the headline would fit but I figured if I make it big enough in width it would push down the headline. Nope, the headline just spanned over, like it covered the figure.

```css
article h2 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #405377;
    padding: 1em;
    clear:both;
    }

    article figure {
    background: #ebe3ff
    }

    article img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 25em;
    min-width: 5em;
    max-height: 13em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }
```

```html
<h2>Headline</h2>
<figure>
 <img src=""alt="image">
 <figcaption>text</figcaption>
</figure>
<p>Text text</p>
```

Comment: You want to move it on some @media restriction (responsive/mobile) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `order: -1;` on the item with `display: flex;` on the container, this will bring that item up to the top.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #F9F9FA;
  background: #a8a8ff;
  padding: 1em;
}
figure {
  background: #ebe3ff;
  order: -1;
}
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 25em;
  min-width: 5em;
  max-height: 13em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h2>Headline</h2>
<figure>
 <img src="#"/>
 <figcaption>text</figcaption>
</figure>
<p>Text text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, @FreshJava. It's been a very handy way of having different layouts on mobile/desktop for me.

Comment: Flexbox workable is Amazing, Order changes your element showing order first to the middle, first to last or last to first etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to simply move the `<h2>` below the image?

Like the following:

```css
article h2 {
 text-align: center;
 color: #405377;
 padding: 1em;
 clear:both;
    }

    article figure {
 background: #ebe3ff
    }

    article img {
 display: block;
 max-width: 25em;
 min-width: 5em;
 max-height: 13em;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
    }
```

```html
<figure>
 <img src=""alt="/>
 <figcaption>text</figcaption>
</figure>
<h2>Headline</h2> <!-- moved the h2 below -->
<p>Text text</p>
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to know if there's a way to do this using CSS.

Comment: i therefore misunderstood the question sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is a outer container with display flex

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) you can find more information about display:flex

Also you had a missing `"` at yout `alt=""` tag

```css
.outer{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column-reverse;
}

article h2 {
 text-align: center;
 color: #405377;
 padding: 1em;
 clear:both;
    }

    article figure {
 background: #ebe3ff
    }

    article img {
 display: block;
 max-width: 25em;
 min-width: 5em;
 max-height: 13em;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<h2>Headline</h2>
<figure>
 <img src=""alt=""/>
 <figcaption>text</figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
<p>Text text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you could just move the actual h2 element and place it under the figure, but it seems you want to see if its possible with css alone.

There are a few ways, not ideal ways, but there are ways:

1. You could adjust the margins of both elements, for example, the h2 element will have a top margin of 50px and the figure element will have a top margin of negative 50px (-50px) (probably one of the worst ways to do it)
2. Another way is to simply give the elements a table layout display of `table-footer-group` and `table-header-group` like this:

```html
<h2 style="display: table-footer-group;">Headline</h2>
<figure style="display: table-header-group;">
 <img src="" alt="">
 <figcaption>text</figcaption>
</figure>
<p>Text text</p>
```